# What am I doing Wrong with this C++ code?

Tags: c++

Sorry, forgot the code

Here is the incorrect code.
I have been trying to get this working, but all the logical operators do not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string repeat;
string repeatnum;
string prompt = "|-[]->";
int main()
{
string entry;
bool Running = true;
while(Running == true)
{
cout << "\n";
cout << prompt;
cin >> entry;
if(entry == "Exit") return 0;
if(entry == "Help") cout << "HELP:\nThsi is a simple program, try an input";
if(entry == "ChangePrompt")
{
    cout << "What do you want to change the prompt to?: ";
    cin >> prompt;
}
if(entry == "Repeat" || "repeat")
{
    cout << "What string do you want to repeat?: ";
    cin >> repeat;
    cout << "How many times do you want to repeat" << repeat << "(1-9)?: ";
    cin >> repeatnum;
    if(repeatnum > 0){}
}
}
char f;
cin >> f;
return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
Error:
C:\Users\Packard Bell\Desktop\test\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Packard Bell\Desktop\test\main.cpp|29|error: no match for 'operator>' in 'repeatnum > 0'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: You didn't post any code.

Comment: It seems that 'repeatnum' is not a number.

Answer (score 2):

Because at line 29 in `main.cpp` you attempt to do `repeatnum > 0` and `repeatnum` is a type with no overloaded `operator >`.

Comment: I do not understand, could you care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the repeatnum problem, this piece of code isn't doing what you want

```
if(entry == "Repeat" || "repeat")
```

It should be

```
if(entry == "Repeat" || entry == "repeat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now after seeing the code. repeatnum is a string. You read input to the string and then compare it with integer. Now string does not have operator>-defined for integer so you need to convert the string to integer before comparison.

```
atoi(repeatnum.c_str());
```

Or use stringstream to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the given info, I can only guess that the variable `repeatnum` is an object of a class or structure which you cannot use to directly compare it with `0`. If the type of `repeatnum` is defined by you, add a member function that overloads `operator >` and handle it properly.

```
class YourType
{
    // Class definition
public:
    int operator >( int var )
    {
       // Code for comparison
       // return result
    }
};
```